# How to ensemble SVM and CNN classifier using bagging?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification

I am doing a classification of tuberculosis using X-ray images. While I extract the useful features from the X-ray images into a csv file and run SVM with it and get a roughly ~60% accuracy. Meanwhile, My CNN model which is directly train on the images dataset has achieved an accuracy of ~80%. I can find reference online where ensemble method can be used when two models machine learning model or deep learning model, not one with another. Example, I can ensemble CNN with another type of CNN.

Comment: BTW, deep learning models *are* machine learning models...

Comment: yes @desertnaut, just want to clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is 'How to ensemble SVM & CNN classifier using bagging' it's not that hard. You train each model SVM and CNN ( You can use multiples of each) with subset of the entire train set. After each model has been trained you give test data, and for each data all models makes a classification. It would work like a vote. SVM votes 'True' and CNN also votes 'true' majority is 'true' so your ensemble model will classify it to 'True'.

So it doesn't matter if its another type of model.

Comment: so lets say SVM votes 'true' and CNN votes 'false', which one should I use?

Comment: @QiYang One option, you can give them weights. Maybe based on each model's accuracy, if SVM has 60% and CNN has 80%, then 0.6 for true, 0.8 for false, the answer of the ensemble model would be false.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap aggregating or bagging is an ensembling method where you have different models trained on different samples of the training set. So, Bagging is not applicable here.

In the case of ensembling a CNN and SVM model, a simple method would be to average the predictions. There are other techniques like weighing(more votes for the accurate model) etc. Please refer this link:

https://mlwave.com/kaggle-ensembling-guide/